# Bluetooth connection error

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, blueman

I have HP laptop notebook  245-G4. After installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, my device initially connected to Bluetooth successfully. However, after rebooting, the Bluetooth in my device is turned on but no devices are showing up on nearby devices list.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following commands and show us the output,

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service      # Check status of the bluetooth service
```

If your Bluetooth service is not running then try:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service      # Enable the bluetooth service, if not already.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `bt-device -l`

Your laptop model is likely to have RTL8821CE, bluetooth and wifi come from the same interface. So you're not lucky with 22.04, last good version was 18.04, but.

Make sure you install `sudo apt install bluez` and try running things from there. Also make sure no rfkill is blocking it by `rfkill unblock all`